# I have accidently deleted xcode project file, but I have on itunes connect Xcode 7.3

Tags: xcode, swift, app-store-connect

I have recently deleted all of the files of my xcode project, but I have summited my latest build to itunes connect, is there any way I can retrieve my build from itunes connect, or do I have to recover it some other way. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It seems quite obvious that he doesn't have one.

Comment: Ok, I was just researching a bit, can I not recover it from the simulator or something?

Answer (score 2):

> is there any way I can retrieve my build

**No** there isn't any way to retrieve *the code*.

You didn't upload your code but a compiled version of your app.

If you've deleted the code, game over.

> do I have to recover it some other way

There's no way to recover a whole project that has been deleted. Even professionnal data recovery solutions are not able to recover 100% and they're extremely expensive anyway.

In the future, **always** backup your data - for a developer, this is not an option. Just do it.

Also, you *should* use version control, like Git - one of the advantages is that you can push the repository to an external location, like Github, offering another way to backup (the more the better).

Answer (score 1):

You can get some assets back by right clicking on your .ipa that you used for the app store and selecting "Open With -> Archive Utility" then in the file inside the Payload folder, right click and use "Show Package Contents"